# Visual Studio 2015 Installation error - webtoolsextensionsvs14.msi

Tags: visual-studio-2015, enterprise

I've been having problems with my Visual Studio 2015 installation ever since I tried to install update 2. I tried installing update 3 in hopes of patching any issues but it kept crashing so I had to uninstall it.

During my reinstall, I'm getting a prompt looking for webtoolsextensionsvs14.msi. It asks me for this several times but when I point the dialog at the file within my Mounted ISO directory, it says it is not a valid installation package. Any ideas on how to fix this so I can get a clean install?

Comment: I also get this problem. I have used the 3rd party uninstall tool, done web installs, iso installs, I got the MSI directly from MS.  Nothing works. I guess just some bug.  The frustrating thing is that each install takes a lifetime, and sometimes just hangs at this part! Very close to full Rage but hey ho.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have a pre-release version of VS, 2014 maybe.  You can download the offending MSI from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48178